# How do I check if a given date includes at least each of the document group listed for user?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, between

I want to develop a SQL query to check if a given date is in at least each of document group.
The following the table

```
DocID    UserID     StartDAte     EndDAte     OfficialName
1        1         10/1/18       10/3/18       A
2        1         10/5/18       10/10/18      A
3        1         10/1/18       10/9/18       B
4        1         10/1/18       10/9/18       C
5        1         10/1/18       10/5/18       D
6        1         10/7/18       10/20/18      D
```

There are 4 document groups namely, A,B,C,D. Need to check if a given date is in atleast each of the documents in each group.

```
eg date : 10/2/18 is in first record of A,B,C, and first record of D. So it is passed.
eg date : 10/4/18 is not in either of documents in A hence failed.
eg date : 10/8/18 is second document in A,B,C, and second document in D hence passed.
eg date : 10/6/18 is in A but not in D hence failed.
```

Since I have to write this for a given user and date, I have to use "IN" clause for "OfficialName" but how could I add "OR" to check date is in any of the files in each "OfficialName" group for all documents for the given user ?

Any help is appreciated.
Need to add something not clear. Number of documents in Official name is not fixed. It could be one or many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate and get the distinct count of groups. If you get 4, you have a match otherwise you don't.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t.officialname)
       FROM elbat t
       WHERE t.userid = <given user>
             AND t.startdate <= <given date>
             AND t.enddate >= <given date>;
```

You can also add a `HAVING count(DISTINCT t.officialname) = 4` to get an empty set if and only if there's no match.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT t.officialname)
  FROM elbat t
  WHERE @date between t.startDate  AND t.enddate and
     t.userid = @userId;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select (case when count(distinct t.officialname) = 4 then 'passed' else 'failed' end) as flag_4groups
from t
where @date <= t.startdate and
      @date >= t.enddate and
      t.user_id = @user;
```

If you want this for all users (but a given date):

```
select t.user_id,
       (case when count(distinct t.officialname) = 4 then 'passed' else 'failed' end) as flag_4groups
from t
where @date <= t.startdate and
      @date >= t.enddate
group by t.user_id
```